# Why multi-value of log results in its non-differentiability?

Tags: complex-analysis

Here is a text from the book *Complex Variables and Applications* by Churchill :
[image]

I don't understand the last paragraph at all. Why $F(z)$ is not differentiable? What does this mean "So $C$ does not lie in any domain throughout which $F'(z) = 1/z$? and more important than anything Why multi-value of log results in its non-differentiability? meaning even if it is multi-value it's derivative exists and equal to $1/z$.

Simple clear explanation would be much appreciated.

Comment: See the definition of logarithm in C, 1/z^2 has a primitive, while 1/z no

Comment: @HenryW. that question is based on calculation directly done by explicit writing of variable in polar co. My question is about the reason and I don't understand that reason which is written in the last paragrph of the text.

Comment: @vvnitram - yes, but my question is why multi-value of log results in its non-differentiabilty meaning even if it is multi-value it's derivitive exists and equal to $1/z$

Comment: @HenryW. - I edited, thanks. btw, the book hasn't talked about Cauchy's Integral Theorem yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The natural logarithm behaves strangely in the complex plane. It is multivalued. The [wikipedia page for complex logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm#Problems_with_inverting_the_complex_exponential_function) has a nice picture demonstrating this behavior. Of course, we prefer to use normal single-valued functions. So we make branch cuts. Making a branch cut means that we choose a ray in the complex plane and "cut" the function into many pieces along that ray. We then choose one of the pieces to work with. Here is an example of such a choice:

[image]

notice that it is not defined along the negative real axis. This is why it is not differentiable here. It's also why the integral is nonzero. The integral, in effect, measures the "jump" the sheet makes along the negative real axis.

Comment: so it is not differentiable just because it is not defined? actually I am wondering why it is not differentiable more importantly as it may much help my confusion.

Comment: Yes. In order for $f'(z)$ to exist, $f(z)$ has to exist. Go back to the definition of the derivative.